# Implementing SEO friendly URLs in Sitecore-uCommerce

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ucommerce

I am implementing a default Sitecore-uCommerce SEO friendly URLs mechanics and I run into issues.

I looked into ItemResolver processor of uCommerce and I still do not understand how uCommerce sets the Sitecore Context Item. It seems like it uses an uCommerce Item's Guid for Sitecore.Context.Item. Somehow it is not the case, but I do not see the real Sitecore Item to be set as Context item. And uCommerce items do not have the layout details on them. Or am I wrong?

```cs
private ID FindSitecoreIdForProduct(int productId)
{
    IRepository<Product> repository = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<IRepository<Product>>();
    Product product = repository.Get(productId);
    if (product != null)
    {
        return new ID(product.Guid);
    }
    return ID.Null;
}
```

Then it makes

```cs
ID iD = this.FindSitecoreIdForProduct(productId);
if (iD == ID.Null)
{
    return;
}
Context.Item = Context.Database.GetItem(iD);
```

I would like it to be a specific Sitecore Item with a rendering showing the product details. The URLs are of type

```
http://sitename.com/productdetailpage/productname/c-25/p-125
```

If you could just explain me how uCommerce gets to the real Sitecore Item and sets it as a Context.Item, I guess it will be enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way.

They move the context item to other item. I didn't like how they deal with url, and I need other ProductResolver.

Ucommerce have products in his own db, and they created a dataProvider to bring products into Sitecore.

The Ucommerce products are located in Sitecore under /sitecore/uCommerce/Products .

The shops,category and subcategory are located under /sitecore/uCommerce/Store.

Please check this link to have a clean idea how ucommerce is dealing with url:

http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v7.0/sitecore/working-with-nice-urls-in-sitecore.html

I also have the same issue like you and I created a custom ItemResolver.

I defined processor in this way on httpRequestBegin pipeline.

```html
<processor type="NameSpace.ProductResolver, Assembly" patch:instead="processor[@type='UCommerce.Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemResolver, UCommerce.Sitecore']"/>
```

I created in Sitecore a new template name ProductPage, I create a new item named Product of type ProductPage

My requirements was to have url like : /Shoes/Running/NIKEAIRZOOMPEGASUS33

When you browse to /category/subcategory/productid my productResolver is triggered.

I check if category,subcategory and product exist.

If they exist I set the current category and current product.

SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentProduct=current_product;
   //you need to check if product is in current category

I set my Context Item to be the Product item

```cs
var pathList = args.LocalPath.Split(new[] { '/' },   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();


var currentProduct= GetCurrentProduct(pathList);  
// in above function I am getting the current product, checking if is correct category and subcategory
if (currentProduct != null)
{
    SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentProduct = currentProduct;
            Sitecore.Context.Item = productItem;
}
```

Comment: Actually uCommerce sets the uCommerce item as Context item. So much so, that you can even set the layout details on it (I put it on the template standard values). Then you should publish templates and uCommerce items; and it creates actual Sitecore items in Web DB. So finally I even begin to like it. Thank you for your contribution, I will accept it as the answer.